# How does like query work with indexed table

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, full-text-indexing

I am working in Spring-java and mysql.

I have to query the table of size `100k records`. Table has say 10 columns.
And In my sql select query I have to make like queries with %text% search on say 4 columns. Those 4 columns are varchar(200), having average text size of 30 character.

I have gone through few blogs and SO answers to understand about index and after reading I came to this question.

Will making those 4 columns individually `FULLTEXT` index, makes difference in execution time of like query?

Comment: no distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)), thanks are never part of good question

Comment: I got answer for this question over [dba community](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/95661/58318)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `FULLTEXT` index, `like` with some certain char starter will use the index. Eg `a like 'hello%'`.But when you use a like begin with `%`, the index wouln't work. You can test it by yourself using `explain`.